# Sub query in Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query in sql stored procedure. I want to get record from other query from its id how I do that.

```
SELECT t.Name ,t.CreatedDate ,t.CreatedBy , t.Amount
      ,t.Margin ,t.Probability ,t.Id 
FROM (SELECT a = 1) a 
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        Name = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.Name 
       ,CreatedDate=HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn 
       ,CreatedBy=HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SystemUserBase.FullName
       ,Amount = totalamount 
       ,Probability=CloseProbability 
       ,Id=SalesOrderId
       ,Margin=(SELECT ( ISNULL( ((Sum(Price)-Sum(CurrentCost)) / NULLIF( Sum(Price), 0 ))*100, 0 ) ) 
                FROM HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.ProductBase 
                JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase 
                  ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase.ProductId = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.ProductBase.ProductId 
                JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase 
                  ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase.SalesOrderId)
     FROM HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase 
     JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.OpportunityBase 
       ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.Opportunityid = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.OpportunityBase.Opportunityid 
     JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SystemUserBase 
       ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SystemUserBase.SystemUserId = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.CreatedBy
    WHERE YEAR(HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn)=YEAR(GETDATE())
```

I want Margin from every record I want Output like
[image]

Comment: Your query has bad syntax. You probably didn't copy all of it. Edit your question, cut the existing code, and paste the full SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to get margin of every record how I filter margin query for SalesOrderId
like

```
Margin=(SELECT ( ISNULL( ((Sum(Price)-Sum(CurrentCost)) / NULLIF( Sum(Price), 0 ))*100, 0 ) ) 
                FROM HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.ProductBase 
                JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase 
                  ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase.ProductId = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.ProductBase.ProductId 
                JOIN HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase 
                  ON HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderDetailBase.SalesOrderId 
Where HirschInternational_MSCRM.dbo.SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId= //SalesOrderId that I get in main query)
```

how I pass that SalesOrderId in this query

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but you *might* be looking for something like

```
select *
from (your SQL SELECT statement goes here) t1
where id = ?;
```